# Launch Different View Layout based on JSON Key Values

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

In my android application, I want to display different App Layout based on JSON Config files from server, For example if config  Layout key is Set to ListView than show ListView when App Launched, Same way if Config Layout key is set to GridView than show GridView in app.

For this purpose I have :

```
public void sendView(View view) throws JSONException, IOException{ 

        String[] viewType = pm.getScreetypeConfigFromJsonElement();

      if ( viewType[0] == "LV"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AUListView.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(){....}  //For any other view

    }
```

And now Im calling this function inside MainActivity

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                 try {
                sendView(/*Cant solve how to pass view */);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                . 
                .
                .
}
```

How can I fix this issue of having to Launch different AppLayout Based on JSON Config Values in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One simple solution is to make different layouts and call `setContentView()` depending on the one you want. For example, make 2 layouts for your activity. One of them has a `ListView` and another one has a `GridView` say. You can inflate based on that:

```
 String[] viewType = pm.getScreetypeConfigFromJsonElement();
    if ( viewType[0] == "LV"){
                setContentView(R.layout.main_layout_with_list_view);
    else if  ( viewType[0] == "GV"){
                setContentView(R.layout.main_layout_with_grid_view);
```

You can put this code in your `onCreate()` method to dynamically inflate the layout based on your JSON values.

Answer (score 0):

after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); call the method where you are checking the json keys in that method use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in your conditions

```
if(viewType[0]== type1)
  setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout1);
else if(viewType[0]== type2)
  setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout2);
```

you dont have to have different activities have multilpe layouts and put all the code in this activity and it will work as per your requirement